# asp.net mvc 2.0 - 301 permanent direct

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I've seen a few similar questions to mine but not exactly what I'm after.

this question shows me how to do the redirect but where/how do I put the extra information in the redirect to tell the search engines that it is a 301?

[ASP.Net MVC - Trapping certain URL's to do 301 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650882/asp-net-mvc-trapping-certain-urls-to-do-301-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public ActionResult Home() {
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.RedirectLocation = "/";
    Response.End();
    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

This works for one off.  If you have multiples, then you'll want to come up with some sort of handler.

One such handler I've used is [Legacy Routing](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx).  It worked out quite well for me.

Comment: Try "Legacy Routing" - I've just posted a link.

Comment: was the example reliable? was it easy enough to implement?